# Using Cauchy condensation test to derive the results about generalized Bertrand series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, induction

The generalized Bertrand series is defined by:

> $$B_{k}:=\sum_{n\ge N}^{ }\frac{1}{n\log n\log\log n\cdot\cdot\cdot\log^{\circ\left(k-1\right)}n\cdot\left(\log^{\circ k}n\right)^{p}},$$

where $N= \left \lfloor{e^{\circ k}\left(0\right)}\right \rfloor +1$, $k \in \mathbb N^{+}$ and $p$ non-negative number.

**Theorem**: The series converges for $p>1$ and diverges for $0<p\le1$.

---

I want to know is it possible to use Cauchy condensation test to derive the same result? since it's been mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), (Of course using Schlömilch's Generalization is also acceptable).

---

Comment: "I really want to know does there exist any other way to use Cauchy condensation test to derive the same result?" What to you mean by any other way?

Answer (score 3):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Here is an approach using telescoping. Since$$
(\ln^{\circ k} x)' = \left( \prod_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \ln^{\circ j} x \right)^{-1}
$$
by the chain rules, then$$
\int \left( (\ln^{\circ k} x)^p \prod_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \ln^{\circ j} x \right)^{-1} \,\d x = \int \frac{\d(\ln^{\circ k} x)}{(\ln^{\circ k} x)^p} =\begin{cases}
-\dfrac{p - 1}{(\ln^{\circ k} x)^{p - 1}}; & p ≠ 1\\
\ln^{\circ k + 1} x; & p = 1
\end{cases}.
$$
Define $f_p(x) := \left( (\ln^{\circ k} x)^p \prod\limits_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \ln^{\circ j} x \right)^{-1}$. Note that no matter $p \geqslant 0$ or $p < 0$, there exists an integer $M_p \geqslant N := [\mathrm{e}^{\circ k}(0)] + 1$ such that $f_p$ is decreasing on $[M_p, +∞)$.

**Case 1:** $p < 1$. For $n \geqslant M_p$,$$
f_p(n) = \int_n^{n + 1} f_p(n) \,\d x \geqslant \int_n^{n + 1} f_p(x) \,\d x = (1 - p) ((\ln^{\circ k} (n + 1))^{1 - p} - (\ln^{\circ k} n)^{1 - p}),
$$
thus\begin{gather*}
\sum_{n = N_p}^∞ f_p(n) \geqslant \sum_{n = M_p}^∞ f_p(n) \geqslant (1 - p) \sum_{n = M_p}^∞ ((\ln^{\circ k} (n + 1))^{1 - p} - (\ln^{\circ k} n)^{1 - p})\\
= (1 - p) \lim_{n → ∞} ((\ln^{\circ k} (n + 1))^{1 - p} - (\ln^{\circ k} M_p)^{1 - p}) = +∞.
\end{gather*}

**Case 2:** $p = 1$. For $n \geqslant M_p$,$$
f_p(n) = \int_n^{n + 1} f_p(n) \,\d x \geqslant \int_n^{n + 1} f_p(x) \,\d x = \ln^{\circ k + 1} (n + 1) - \ln^{\circ k + 1} n,
$$
and $\sum\limits_{n = N_p}^∞ f_p(n)$ diverges analogously.

**Case 3:** $p > 1$. For $n \geqslant M_p + 1$,$$
f_p(n) = \int_{n - 1}^n f_p(n) \,\d x \leqslant \int_{n - 1}^n f_p(x) \,\d x = (p - 1) \left( \frac{1}{(\ln^{\circ k} n)^{p - 1}} - \frac{1}{(\ln^{\circ k} (n + 1))^{p - 1}} \right),
$$
thus\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \sum_{n = N_p}^∞ f_p(n) = \sum_{n = N_p}^{M_p} f_p(n) + \sum_{n = M_p}^∞ f_p(n)\\
&\leqslant \sum_{n = N_p}^{M_p} f_p(n) + (p - 1) \sum_{n = M_p}^∞ \left( \frac{1}{(\ln^{\circ k} n)^{p - 1}} - \frac{1}{(\ln^{\circ k} (n + 1))^{p - 1}} \right)\\
&= \sum_{n = N_p}^{M_p} f_p(n) + \frac{p - 1}{(\ln^{\circ k} M_p)^{p - 1}} < +∞.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the condensation test.

> **Lemma 1:** If $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are sequences of positive numbers such that $y_n \geqslant M$ for some constant $M > 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n → ∞} \dfrac{x_n}{y_n} = 1$, then $\lim\limits_{n → ∞} \dfrac{\ln x_n}{\ln y_n} = 1$.
>
> **Lemma 2:** For any integer $k \geqslant 2$,$$
> \lim_{n → ∞} \frac{\ln^{\circ k}(2^n)}{\ln^{\circ k - 1} n} = 1.
> $$

(Lemma 2 can be proved by induction on $k$ with Lemma 1.)

Now return to the question and prove by induction on $k$. For $k = 0$, it is well-known that$$
\sum \frac{1}{n^p} < +∞ \Longleftrightarrow p > 1.
$$
For $k = 1$, note that $\dfrac{1}{2^n (\ln(2^n))^p} = \dfrac{1}{(\ln 2)^p · 2^n n^p}$, thus by the condensation test,$$
\sum \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^p} < +∞ \Longleftrightarrow \sum 2^n · \frac{1}{2^n (\ln(2^n))^p} < +∞ \Longleftrightarrow \sum \frac{1}{n^p} < +∞ \Longleftrightarrow p > 1.
$$
Now assume that$$
\sum \left( (\ln^{\circ k} n)^p \prod_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \ln^{\circ j} n \right)^{-1} < +∞ \Longleftrightarrow p > 1
$$
for some $k \geqslant 1$. Note that by Lemma 2,\begin{gather*}
(\ln^{\circ k + 1}(2^n))^p \prod_{j = 0}^k \ln^{\circ j}(2^n) = 2^n · n \ln 2 · (\ln^{\circ k + 1}(2^n))^p \prod_{j = 2}^k \ln^{\circ j}(2^n)\\
\sim 2^n · n \ln 2 · (\ln^{\circ k} n)^p \prod_{j = 2}^k \ln^{\circ j - 1} n = 2^n \ln 2 · (\ln^{\circ k} n)^p \prod_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \ln^{\circ j} n
\end{gather*}
as $n → ∞$, thus by the condensation test,\begin{gather*}
\sum \left( (\ln^{\circ k + 1} n)^p \prod_{j = 0}^k \ln^{\circ j} n \right)^{-1} < +∞ \Longleftrightarrow \sum 2^n · \left( (\ln^{\circ k + 1}(2^n))^p \prod_{j = 0}^k \ln^{\circ j}(2^n) \right)^{-1} < +∞\\
\Longleftrightarrow \sum \left( (\ln^{\circ k} n)^p \prod_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \ln^{\circ j} n \right)^{-1} < +∞ \Longleftrightarrow p > 1.
\end{gather*}
End of induction.

---

*Proof of Lemma 2:* For $k = 2$,$$
\lim_{n → ∞} \frac{\ln(\ln(2^n))}{\ln n} = \lim_{n → ∞} \frac{\ln(n\ln 2)}{\ln n} = \lim_{n → ∞} \frac{\ln n + \ln(\ln 2)}{\ln n} = 1 + \lim_{n → ∞} \frac{\ln(\ln 2)}{\ln n} = 1.
$$
Assume the proposition holds for $k$, then by Lemma 1,$$
\lim_{n → ∞} \frac{\ln^{\circ k + 1}(2^n)}{\ln^{\circ k} n} = \lim_{n → ∞} \frac{\ln(\ln^{\circ k}(2^n))}{\ln(\ln^{\circ k - 1} n)} = 1.
$$
End of induction.

Comment: yes you are right about the identity,so I think the base case should be $k=3$, because as I said for $k=2$ we have a problem

Comment: what is $x_n$ and $y_n$ is your base case?

Comment: @user715522 To reiterate, Lemma 1 is not used in the base case $k=2$ but in the inductive step, e.g. from $k=2$ to $k=3$.

Comment: I got it, thanks , van you just tell me how did you use limit comparison test?

Comment: no no, I just cannot fully understand how lemma 2 has been used here (how limit comparison test has been used here)

Comment: @user715522 It's used in proving$$2^n·n\ln2·(\ln^{\circ k+1}(2^n))^p\prod_{j=2}^k\ln^{\circ j}(2^n)\sim2^n·n\ln2·(\ln^{\circ k}n)^p\prod_{j=2}^k\ln^{\circ j-1}n$$by multiplying $\ln^{\circ j}(2^n)\sim\ln^{\circ j-1}n$ for $2\leqslant j\leqslant k$.

Comment: you are right bu limit comparison test claims: If $$
\lim_{n → ∞} \frac{\ln^{\circ k}(2^n)}{\ln^{\circ k - 1} n} = 1>0.$$ and $\sum_{n}^{ }\log^{\circ \left(k-1\right)}n$ converges, then so does $\sum_{n}^{ }\ln^{\circ k}(2^n)$,however I understand your proof now ,but you said you've used limit comparison test,however I don't know how

Comment: So 


$$\sum_{n}^{ }\ln^{\circ 1}\left(n\right) \;\; \text{converges} \implies \sum_{n}^{ }\ln^{\circ 2}\left(2^n\right)\;\; \text{converges} $$

$$\sum_{n}^{ }\ln^{\circ 2}\left(n\right) \;\; \text{converges} \implies \sum_{n}^{ }\ln^{\circ 3}\left(2^n\right)\;\; \text{converges} $$
Continuing follows:

$$\sum_{n}^{ }\ln^{\circ k}\left(n\right) \;\; \text{converges} \implies \sum_{n}^{ }\ln^{\circ \left(k-1\right)}\left(2^n\right)\;\; \text{converges} $$

Then how did you continue?

Comment: @user715522 Those're not the series to which I applied the test. They should be the ones I connected with $\Longleftrightarrow$.